# Slider with RadLoadingPanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, slider

I'm using Telerik AJAX Slider. I want to show TelerikLoadingPanel when the Slider changes. I'm getting the TelerikLoadingPanel for all the other controls but not for the RADSLider.
I'm using the following JQUERy:

```
$('#<%=slider1.ClientID%>').live("OnClientSlide", function(){ShowLoadingPanel();});
```

Comment: I'm confused.. are you using the Telerik AJAX controls in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is included in the UpdatedControls collection of your RadAjaxManager's AjaxSetting and that the entry has a loading panel set.
Then, adding a handler for a client-side event is done via the ScriptControl instance, not via jQuery, see [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/slider-client-object.html), the "Adding and Removing Client-Side Events" section. You only need to pass the function object reference to the method.